# React native navigate to same page with different props

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-drawer

I am working on a RN app that uses a side-drawer.(RN version: 0.59.8)

```
const DrawerNavigator = createDrawerNavigator(
    {
        Home: {
            screen: HomeScreen
        },
        Poems: {
            screen: PoemsScreen
        },
        Contest: {
            screen: ContestScreen
        },
        AboutMe: {
            screen: AboutMeScreen
        }
    },
    DrawerConfig
);

export default createAppContainer(DrawerNavigator);
```

The react-navigation version in use is 3.11.0.
In the menu, multiple subitems point to the same page, a ViewPager, but with different params (the page index).
The problem is that none of the below worked:

1. trying to use push instead of navigate (returned `_this2.props.navigation.push is not a function`)
2. trying to reset the respective stack.

```
const resetAction = StackActions.reset({
   index: 0,
   key: 'Poems',
   actions: [NavigationActions.navigate({ routeName: 'Poems' })]
})
this.props.navigation.dispatch(resetAction)
```

(also tried with `key: null`)

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: this.props.navigation.navigate('Poems', { key: 1})

Comment: @GokulKulkarni thanks for your insight but it is not working :(

Comment: I could not understand your question correctly, please help understand. You want to navigate to the same page with different params?

Answer (score 15):

Try reading https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/navigating.html#navigate-to-a-route-multiple-times

you need to use navigation.push() to run copies of your component with different params.

Comment: This did not work for me as I'm using the SwitchNavigator. The props.navigation.push() method can only be used if you are using the StackNavigator. Otherwise, this will result in an error saying props.navigation.push is undefined or not a function. Check this : https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/navigation-prop.html

Answer (score -2):

add data to to navigate function

```
this.props.navigation.navigate('routeName', { data })
```

eg: `this.props.navigation.navigate('BookDetails', { book: this.props.book })`